# How to change Openlayers layer switcher control to display radio buttons for non-baselayers

Tags: openlayers

If a layer is added to the OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher with isBaseLayer:false, then it will appear with a check box, while baselayers get added with a radio button, so that only one can be active at a time. Is is possible to change the default, so that non-baselayers also appear with radio buttons instead of check boxes.

Comment: Yes, set isBaseLayer:true on the layer, then they will become radio buttons in the LayerSwitcher control.

Comment: Hi John i want to have radio button features for non-base map layers.

Comment: I think you will have to override the the redraw function, see lines 292 onwards here: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Control/LayerSwitcher.js